# Native UI Confirm Dialog LibGDX

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm looking for a way to get a yes/no dialog box to display for android.

I'm looking for something that functions similar to this:

```
Gdx.input.getTextInput(new TextInputListener() {
            @Override
            public void input (String text) {
            }

            @Override
            public void canceled () {

            }
        }, "Question", "");
```

Except, instead of getting text input, I want it to simply prompt the user for a yes or no.

I've looked into [this](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/NativeUIConfirmDialog), but I haven't been able to get it to work, as it's probably pretty out-dated. If anyone could think of a solution to this, that'd be wonderful. Thanks so much!

Comment: What exactly going wrong with example from GDX-Users? At first look it's completely ok. Anyway you'll should use approach like that to implement android native dialog - there is no another way. Post some code to understand errors.

Comment: Under:
    gameView = initialize(new ConfirmTest(this), false);
Eclipse says: Type mismatch: Cannot convert from void to view

Comment: Yes, it's really deprecated. Wait for a minute - I'll post with correctives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change your Activity to look like this. Everything else (e.g. RequestHandler) should be correct.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initialize(new ConfirmTest(this), false);
}

@Override
public void confirm(final ConfirmInterface confirmInterface) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(ConfirmTestAndroidActivity.this)                                     
            .setTitle("Confirm")
            .setMessage("Are you sure?")                                            
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    confirmInterface.yes();
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
           .create().show();        
   }        
});
}
```

To use custom configuration you can use this:

```
Game myGame = new Game(); // your game class which implements ApplicationListener

AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
cfg.useGL20 = true;
cfg.useCompass = false;
cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
cfg.useWakelock = true;
cfg.touchSleepTime = 16;

initialize(myGame, cfg);
```

Remember that using WakeLock feature requires permission in AndroidManifest.xml to be declared or SecurityException will be thrown.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: All is well in Eclipe now. It shows no errors. The only problem now is that when I run the app on my android phone, It says, "Unfortunately game has stopped running."

Comment: I've edited my answer - look for permission in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Its still giving me the say error: "Unfortunately game has stopped running."

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/Rr43YchJ
And also, could I mention that you're an amazing human being, and more people should be like you :) I appreciate your help so much.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31053/discussion-between-vyacheslav-and-chance-leachman)

Comment: Hi, this code work fine, but if a set Holo Theme to the Dialog, then appear a double Dialog, how can I remove the second one? http://i.imgur.com/d8NPHUV.png

Comment: @TonyCeralva hmm, pretty interesting - I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use gdx-dialogs library. Instructions to use it here: https://github.com/TomGrill/gdx-dialogs

You can build these kinds of native dialogs:

- GDXProgressDialog: For loading dialog
- GDXTextPrompt: For text input
- GDXButtonDialog: For multi-options pop-up

And it works on iOS, Android and Desktop